# Spyder: Syntax highlighting for optional arguments

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Spyder 3.1.4 (Python 3.6.1 64bits, Qt 5.6.2, PyQt5 5.6 on Linux).

The question is very simple:

Can I highlight the optional arguments in Spyder, such as `dtype` or `copy` in the following example?
(it's Visual Studio Code)

[image]

If I can't, is there a reason for it not implemented to Spyder?

I couldn't find any document/settings dealing with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) It's not possible to highlight keyword arguments in Spyder, sorry. We simply don't consider it an important feature to have, so it hasn't been implemented yet.

If this is important to you, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we try to address it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I will open an issue then :)